# How to speed up SQLite access on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, performance

I'm doing both an update and an insert to a review_schedule table. It seems as if the time for the both takes between 1 and 2 seconds, which is a bit slow.  I've tried it with and without indexes set on the id field and the date_review field. Note that I'm using a precompiled statement for the insert, but not the update, because the compiled statement for update apparently isn't supported in Gingerbread. Here's the code:

```
public long insert(int id, String lastReviewDate, String nextReviewDate) {

    this.insertStmt.bindLong(1, id);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(2, lastReviewDate);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(3, nextReviewDate);

    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();

}

public void updateSRSInfo(int id, String lastReviewDate,
        String nextReviewDate) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("last_review_date", lastReviewDate);
    contentValues.put("next_review_date", nextReviewDate);
    this.myDataBase.update(DataBaseHelper.WORD_REVIEW_SCHEDULE,
            contentValues, "_id=?", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });

}
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't worry. It happened to me once, too. I think that if you downvote a question that is, at least in appearance, well formatted and asked, people should at least comment to help us improve (that's the whole point, isn't?). Mind you, I have no idea to the solution of your question, just came here to add one up for you and wish you good luck!

Comment: Is the length of the procedure making the App unresponsive? If that's the case maybe you can move the operation into a different thread.

Comment: @roman - that's a good idea, I'll think about it. It's not really unresponsive typically 1-2 seconds. A thread would make it quicker but is riskier as well.

Comment: @roman - I put the update into an AsyncTask and it's working great. If you make an answer out of it I'll accept it.

Comment: @Jack - Done! Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the procedure making the App unresponsive, maybe you can move the operation into a different thread.

Comment: Thanks. For future googlers, I suggest putting in an AsyncTask, as this is the recommended method for threading in Android.

Answer (score 0):

At least two options:

1) Read uncommitted transactions, since by default SQLite reads only committed transactions, which is slow. But you have to understands all risks which you migth have [reading uncommitted records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Dirty_reads). Changing transaction isolation level can be done in this way:

```
database.execSQL("PRAGMA read_uncommitted = true;");
```

2) Use tables indexing

Answer (score 0):

As you already have got an id,why not combine it with ContentUri.withAppendedId,then you can access this record directly.
i'm not sure whether this run faster or not  as i haven't test this.